# RTI DDS - not enough available space in CDR buffer

Tags: data-distribution-service

I am playing back DDS data from a recorded database, and have written a Java program to listen for the data.  I am able to receive most of the messages fine, but I am getting some consistent exceptions that look like the following:

```
PRESCstReaderCollator_storeSampleData:!deserialize
java.lang.IllegalStateException: not enough available space in CDR buffer
    at com.rti.dds.cdr.CdrBuffer.checkSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.rti.dds.cdr.CdrInputStream.readShortFromBigEndian(Unknown Source)
    at com.rti.dds.cdr.CdrInputStream.deserializeAndSetCdrEncapsulation(Unknown Source)
    at <my type>.deserialize_key_sample(<my type>TypeSupport.java:456)
    at com.rti.dds.topic.TypeSupportImpl.deserialize_key(Unknown Source)
    at com.rti.dds.topic.TypeSupportImpl.deserialize_keyI(Unknown Source)
```

Has anyone seen this or know what might cause this?

EDIT: I should also add that I am currently receiving DDS data via a replayed database, using rtireplay.  I started receiving this error after dropping in a new replay configuration that I was given to use.  So maybe the question is what replay configuration settings could affect something like this?  I am also posting obfuscated @key fields in IDL at request

```
struct MyType{
    Key1 key1; //@key
    Key2 key2; //@key
    ...
}

struct Key1 {
    long long m; //@key
    long long l; //@key
    ...
}

//key members only
struct Key2 {
    Key1 a; //@key
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting an (obfuscated) definition of the IDL of the type that you experience this with? In particular, what do(es) the key attribute(s) look like?

Comment: sure.  do you want the idl or the java source generated from the idl?

Comment: The IDL is fine, thanks.

Comment: sorry for the delay, just got the IDL posted.  The IDL is rather complicated, so i extracted only the key attributes in each type.  Do you need more of the subtypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the stack trace is slightly different, I was able to reproduce a similar case with the following output:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: string length (200)
exceeds maximum (10)
    at com.rti.dds.cdr.CdrInputStream.readString(CdrInputStream.java:364)
    at stringStructTypeSupport.deserialize_key_sample(stringStructTypeSupport.java:411)
    at com.rti.dds.topic.TypeSupportImpl.deserialize_key(TypeSupportImpl.java:1027)
    at com.rti.dds.topic.TypeSupportImpl.deserialize_keyI(TypeSupportImpl.java:965)
PRESCstReaderCollator_storeSampleData:!deserialize
```

Note that I am using 5.1.0 which is a bit more verbose in its error messages.

The conditions under which this occurred were the following:

- The DataReader expected a type that had a different key-definition, or to be more precise, a key definition of a different size than what the DataWriter was producing. In my case, the DataWriter produced a string key attribute of 200 characters whereas the DataReader expected a string no longer than 10 characters.
- The DataWriter had a QoS setting of `protocol.serialize_key_with_dispose` set to true, meaning that this inconsistent key is actually used (as opposed to its key hash) for determining the instance in case of a `dispose()`
- In case you are using 5.1.0 or later: the publishing Participant had a QoS setting of `resource_limits.type_code_max_serialized_length` and `resource_limits.type_object_max_serialized_length` both set to 0. This avoids communication of type information and therefore prevents detection of the inconsistency in the definition. Older versions did not check for type consistency in the first place, even if there resource_limits were set to non-zero.
- The error occurred at the moment that an instance was `dispose()`d

Especially `protocol.serialize_key_with_dispose` is not commonly changed and it seems to be the only reason why this `deserialize_key` function might show up in your stack trace. If you check your `rtireplay` configuration and find that this particular settings is set to `true`, then it is highly likely that the scenario described here is your case.

The `serialize_key_with_dispose` setting is to allow for the case where the first sample ever received for a key value happens to be a `dispose`. This means that the instance is not yet known. Normally, the actual key values are not propagated with a dispose, but just a hashed key. This might not be good enough to identify which instance the dispose is intended for. Setting this policy to true results in the full key value being propagated with a dispose. It is related to `propagate_dispose_of_unregistered_instances`. For more details, see section *6.5.3.5 Propagating Serialized Keys with Disposed-Instance Notifications* of the [Connext User's Manual](http://community.rti.com/rti-doc/510/ndds.5.1.0/doc/pdf/RTI_CoreLibrariesAndUtilities_UsersManual.pdf)

Comment: thanks for all the detailed research.  The resource_limits settings you mentioned have matching non-zero values set for the data readers and writers (actually they derive their QoS profiles from the same configuration file).  However, the serialize_key_with_dispose was indeed set to true, so that sounds like what is causing the issue.  What are the reasons to leave that set as is, or should we disable it?

Comment: You are welcome. I have added some explanation on serialize_key_with_dispose. What version of the product do you use?

Comment: Currently using 5.0.0

Comment: OK, that explains why the type inconsistency was not detected by Connext, even though you had the resource_limits settings set to non-zero. I added a minor remark to the answer on this as well. Note that the *real* cause of the problem is not the setting of `serialize_key_with_dispose`, but is the fact that you have inconsistent type definitions in your system, which allowed the DataWriter to write with a key size larger than the DataReader expected. That is something you should check out in the first place.